# Optimize an update query with join and group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-update, query-optimization

I have a table **totals** with fields DATASOURCE, PEOPLEID, TOTVALUE (~6 milion of records) and a table **source1** with field PEOPLEID and VALUE (ab. 3 milion of records).
In **totals** I have peopleids unique for each DATASOURCE, while in **source1** I have several records for each peopleid.
All peopleids in **source1** are already included in **totals**, but not their values.

I managed to get the update query that update the field TOTVALUE of **totals** taking it from **source1** on a "test" small table, but now that I am trying to get it running on the real table it's running forever... and I'll have to repeat it for **source2**, **source3**,  and so on...

The query I run is:

```
UPDATE  totals t
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  peopleid,
                sum(value) AS TotValues
        FROM source1
        GROUP BY peopleid
    ) s
    ON t.peopleid = s.peopleid
SET t.totvalue = s.TotValues
where
t.datasource like 'source1'
```

Do you think there is a better way to run and optimise this query ?

Comment: Sure that set clause is right? I thing you hava a typo and will be: `SET t.TotValues = s.TotValues`  ;)

Answer (score 1):

- use `=` instead of `LIKE` since, *I think*, you are not searching patterns right?
- create an `INDEX` on column `PeopleID` on both tables: `totals` and `source`
- *if possible, add also an index on column `datasource` on table `totals`*

query,

```
UPDATE  totals t
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  peopleid,
                    sum(value) AS TotValues
            FROM    source1
            GROUP   BY peopleid
        ) s
        ON t.peopleid = s.peopleid
SET     t.peopleid = s.peopleid
WHERE   t.datasource = 'source1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining data first.
Remember to create indexes for peopleid column in both tables.

```
UPDATE  totals t
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        select * from (
          SELECT  t.datasource,
                  peopleid,
                  sum(value) AS TotValues
          FROM source1 s INNER JOIN 
               totals t
                      ON t.peopleid = s.peopleid
          GROUP BY t.datasource, t.peopleid
        ) s_aux
    ) s
    ON t.peopleid = s.peopleid and t.datasource = s.datasource
SET t.totvalue = s.TotValues
```

Comment: Thank you.. I am trying to understand this (complex) query.. am I wrong, or here there isn't the condition that the records on **totals** to be updated are only those with field datasource = 'source1' ?

Comment: you say " I'll have to repeat it for source2, source3, and so on.", then I have moved this condition to select to do it in a single transaction. Query is complex because this is a trip to join update table with it self in mysql.

Comment: Given that I'm a newbie on SQL, what I can't get is where is the link between totals.fieldsource (where the info is on a field) and fieldsource table (where the info is on the name of the table) PS: (I may have peopleid on multiple sources)